# jQuery loaded in wrong order for non-admin page views only

Tags: plugins, jquery

I am calling /js/gallery_sugar.js with the following block of code in my plugin. It works fine while viewing the pages logged in as admin, but it doesn't seem to be running when I am just viewing the page without being logged in as admin:

**Here is the code in the plugin:**

```
add_action('init','gallery_sugar_js_init');

function gallery_sugar_js_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gallery_sugar_js', plugins_url( '/js/gallery_sugar.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('/css/gallery_sugar.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style' );
}
```

**Source code while not logged in as admin (This does not work - jquery not called first):**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/projects/lightbox/wp-content/plugins/custom-gallery/js/gallery_sugar.js?ver=3.7'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/projects/lightbox/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/projects/lightbox/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

**Source code while logged in as admin (This works - jquery called first):**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/projects/lightbox/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/projects/lightbox/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/projects/lightbox/wp-content/plugins/custom-gallery/js/gallery_sugar.js?ver=3.7'></script>
```

I am trying to work out what I am doing wrong in that it doesn't display in both cases.

Comment: Hook on to wp_enqueue_scripts instead of init.

Comment: Tried it and it does nothing I am afraid

Comment: Try registering it with a dependency on jquery instead of adding the dependency in the enqueue function.

Comment: By non-admin do you mean Front end view?